# replacing strings in ASP.NET hidden field via JavaScript

Tags: javascript

how can I replace strings in ASP.NET hidden field using JavaScript?

```
var s = document.getElementById('HF').value;
```

where HF is my hidden field, I want to replace some strings in HF value, but s doesn't display replace function, should I convert s to ToString?

thanks

Comment: Can ASP.Net interpret JavaScript?  If not, then you cannot use JavaScript in an ASP context.

Comment: What do you mean "s doesn't display replace function". `s` is a string and it has a method `replace`

Comment: of course I know ASP.NET is different from JavaScript, this was just a line of my JS function

Comment: I mean VS2010 intellisense doesn't display Replace function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean this?

```
var s = document.getElementById('HF').value;
document.getElementById('HF').value = s.replace(/oldstring/g, "newstring");
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/2tzGH/